# Order of imports in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How do you like to arrange your "using xxx" imports in C#? I got bored the other day and put them in order from shortest to longest.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Brian

Comment: I organize them by flavour. Cherriest at the top, Grape-iest at the bottom.

Comment: community wiki? I organise them by strongest to weakest.

Comment: I go by Unused at the top, used at the bottom and unknowns in the middle. and oh! Lettuce, tomatoes and light Mayo.

Comment: bored the other day?  and today it seems...

Comment: ...Just how much time are you spending on this (and does your manager know)?

Comment: I like alphabetical order. *shrug*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I like to right click in the source code editor -> `Organize Usings` -> `Remove and Sort`

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeitwell.com](http://www.codeitwell.com/wp-content/images/27.1.gif))</sub>

Comment: But I also set Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Advance | Place "System" directives first when sorting. So not quite alphabetical.

Comment: I thought you were joking at first. Learned something new today.Thanks! My question was half serious, with a touch of humor. It is after all Friday in the US.

Comment: Good to know because it is already wednesday in the rest of the world

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 you can use the keyboard command Ctrl+R, G

Answer (score 4):

StyleCop rules are the following:

1. System namespaces first.
2. Alphabetical sorting.

Answer (score 3):

[Sort Usings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514113.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do it in alphabetical order for the standard .NET namespaces. I always put custom/3rd part ones at the bottom with my own ones being first (in alphatical order also) e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using MyNamespace.Utils
using MyNamespace.Misc
using 3rdPartyTool.Utils
```